# Feeding a list of URL's to UIWebview

Tags: objective-c

What would be the best way to provide a list of URL's to UIWebview ? I'm using the new pagecurl app preset (in iOS 5 beta ) and replacing the stock UIView by a UIWebview, I realise this is pretty basic but any pointer would be very informative, first I should try to init the UIWebview with a single URL but ultimately I would like to feed a list of urls to be able to use the pagecurl to transition between the different addresses ..

any help would be greatly appreciated .

Thanks !

**EDIT**

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 680, 700)];
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong, you're trying to open multiple URLs in one UIWebView at same time?

Comment: I'm trying to feed multiple url's to a UIWebview so I can use the page curl on it . For example, page one : www.google.com < page curl > on the second page, www.apple.com, etc ...

Comment: So load one url and curl to another url? Use two UIWebView then and curl between them

Comment: ok, would you then create them all at the same time (on top of each other) or programatically create one after an other ?

Comment: one after other, if you use 2 of them, just cycle them: load one, show it, load second, curl to second, load one, curl to one, load second,....

Comment: cool, I get the idea, now I guess I'll have to figure out how to get the message that the page as been turned . One thing I don't understand is why, if I use the code appended above, I keep on "curling" to google.com, I'm just wondering if there is a quicker way to implement it in the same UIWebview ?

Comment: No shortcut to this behavior is available, you have to do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an approach based on managing multiple UIWebviews using a broker based logic. Say you have a broker called WebViewControllerBroker that manages several UIWebViewControllers each associated with a UIWebView then you can use the approach I describe in my iOS application here - https://github.com/aish9r/Reader Feel free to use the code too. I also describe the design philosophy of designing apps similar to your use case in detail.